# How to check a table is empty or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, is-empty

So i have a script like this to make a 2x2 table by javascript

```
function createtable(){
          var tbl = document.getElementById('x');
            if (tbl.contains()==false){
              tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
              var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
              for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {         
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.style.height='50px';
                    td.style.width='50px';
                }
                tbdy.appendChild(tr);
              }
              tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
        }

<form>
    <input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick="createtable()"> <br>
</form>
<table id="x"> </table>
```

I want to check if table x contains anything or not to create itself. Im trying to use the contains() to check but it doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by contains "anything"? Child elements, text?

Answer (score 6):

You can check the number of rows in the table:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
```

See reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp

**Using this:**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('x');
if (tbl.rows.length == 0) {
   // empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if there are any  inside table do this

```
document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length
```

More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_rows)

Answer (score 1):

you can Check the Row Counts

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('x');
if(tbl.rows.length==0){
}
```

if the tbl.rows.length is 0  that means the table don't have any rows

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. One of way, you can use childElementCount property.

```
if (tbl.childElementCount==0)
{

}
```

For more details you can refere [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_childelementcount.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since there are no child elements or text nodes in your table, you can just check to see if the `innerHTML` property is falsy. This prevents your `createtable` function from appending additional children after the function has been run once. For example:

```js
function createtable() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('x');
  if (!tbl.innerHTML) {
    var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
    tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.style.height = '50px';
        td.style.width = '50px';
      }
      
      tbdy.appendChild(tr);
    }
    
    tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick="createtable()">
  <br>
</form>
<table id="x"></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Plain javascript:

```
!![].length
```

or use Lodash

```
_.head([]);
// => undefined
```